# dropdown menu doesn't open - laravel 5

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I can not get out of my application, I'm using the auth out of box login for laravel 5, but when I get out of my account, I'm not successful.

**EDIT:** the problem is that dropdown menu does not open for me to logout.

Can someone help me ?

this is my app.blade.php ->

```
@guest
    <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
@else
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" v-pre>
            {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                    onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                    Logout
                </a>

                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
@endguest
```

Comment: what is the value of `{{route('logout')}}`? Is this route definitely set?

Comment: this is http://localhost:8000/logout, but the problem is that dropdown menu does not open for me to logout

Comment: what happens when you load this page without loading the css? I suspect the dropdown menu is hidden by default.

Comment: you could also try simplifying this down so that it's just the html and then see what happens, if it works you know that css or javascript is preventing the behaviour you want

Comment: What do you mean the dropdown menu doesn't open?  So the issue isn't that the logout isn't working, the issue is your menu doesn't work?  Your question title is pretty poor if you're just talking about the menu not opening.

Comment: I can logout, without css.

Answer (score 1):

@theFlash So CSS is setting the logout button to `style="display: none"` you need to set this to either `display: block;`, `display: inline-block;` or `display: inline;` to get it to show up. At the moment it's hidden by CSS so you can't click it...

Comment: Yes bro display: inline-block; worked perfectly for me.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Adding `app.js` file helped me to open the dropdown

//app.blade.php

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```